# Removing the .php file extension from files on an Apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My question is, I am sure, relatively straightforward and there are several questions about this exact topic already on stackoverflow. I have tried all of the solutions currently posted and none of them seem to work, this could be due to changes in the apache server over time and now it handles parsing a .htaccess file or it could be a configuration setting that isn't mentioned in the posts. Whichever the case an updated answer would be extremely helpful.

There are 2 main goals I have

1) Configure my apache server such that a link to the page [www.example.com/about] makes the web server understand that the page [www.example.com/about.php] should be rendered and shown to the user.

2) Configure my apache server such that a link to the page [www.example.com/about.php] redirects VISIBLY to [www.example.com/about] so that the user does not see the .php extension at the end of the url.

I have read through the [Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4 documentation regarding mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) trying to figure out how to make this happen and I have not yet had success. I've also read through all the current posts on this topic and tried the posted solutions without luck thus far.

Any and all help will be extremely appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1,
Its better to put Alias to achieve. Enter the following line to the VirtualHost container in httpd.conf

> Alias /about /about.php

Then restart the httpd

For 2,
Try editing the httpd.conf and php.ini. From httpd.conf edit the following lines

> ServerTokens Prod
>
> ServerSignature Off

From php.ini edit/add the line

> expose_php = Off

Let us know if that helped you :)